# Approach to write an extension based application

Tags: rust, architecture

I want to write an extension based application, which means an application contains one or multiple program with a primary program (as core for example) and some extensions that aren't necessary but could be added to core to extend features of application. the extension host of vscode is a very good example and interesting. I tried to understand how it works several times and also searched for this approach but nothing found. I want to know how to write a program that can **dynamically** add and remove an small pieces of codes as extension. I don't know how this piece of codes should be, I don't know how they must be loaded/unloaded to/from program, I don't know if each of them should be a separate programs or not and such this "I don't know"s in this context.
I welcome to any idea and guides in this problem.

I usually code in cpp/Rust.

Comment: This can be interesting for you https://nullderef.com/series/rust-plugins/

Comment: @ĐorđeZeljić That was! very good and helpful! thank you